# Trigger OnSubmit() With Ref - How to Pass Event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to programmatically hit my submit button so I made a ref

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.formSubmit = React.createRef();
}

  <form
    ref={this.formSubmit}
    onSubmit={this.searchClick}
  />

this.formSubmit .current.submit(new Event('submit'));
```

So my form does submit, but also my page refreshes so I am guessing my

```js
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
```

are not running.

Comment: did you check your params at runtime for `searchClick`? is `event` the actual event? I think you can also just call `submit` on the form via `this.formSubmit.current.submit()`

Comment: no, what I am trying to do is pass the ref, into another component that will trigger the onSubmit but like I said the submit works, but it does not get stopped and refreshes my whole page.

Comment: I see, the issue is how forms submit when done programatically. They are meant to submit to the server when done programmatically, hence the page submit. You can add a button to the form that is of type submit (you can make it hidden if needed) then trigger a click on that. [See fiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/5njopghw/6/)

Comment: did that help? want me to write it up as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Try this:

```js
 <form
 ref={this.formSubmit}
 onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault() & this.searchClick}
/>
```

Comment: generally its not a good practice to put an inline lambda as an event handler callback. Its better to define this method on the class for rendering performance purposes

Comment: From React Docs:
"In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering."

Comment: exactly what i was calling out, + the new function reference every render cycle :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `event.preventDefault();` in `searchClick`

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of submit in a form is to send the payload and re-direct the page to the place mentioned in action. But since action is absent it will refresh the page. This is browsers default behaviour. To cancel this preventDefault should be called.

Check if event is available in your `searchClick` and call it.

```
searchClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do stuff here
}
```

Edit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault for more

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The point is you mustn't give ref attribute to the form tag and you must submit the form with a submit button on your form tag.

First I made a form with a transparent submit button on it and a Ref like this:

```
const FormSimple = () => {

      const SubmitButton = useRef();

      return (
            <form onSubmit={(e)=>{
                            e.preventDefault()
                            console.log(e);
                           }}>
                  <Button ref={SubmitButton} 
                          type="submit"
                          className="opacity-0 p-0" 
                          style={{height:"3px",display:"inline-block"}}>
                                 submit 
                  </Button>
            </form>
      )};
```

Socond I use a new button to handle submit in another place :

```
<Button type="button" 
        onClick={() => {SubmitButton.current.click();}}>
                Add
</Button>
```

You can use this event everywhere you access the ref.

Finally, my page didn't reload after submitting form.